# firebase2.default.firestore is not a function - React Firebase

Tags: reactjs, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I am trying to use **firestore** in my reactjs app.

When i call firestore from firebase config object.

It says

> firebase2.default.firestore is not a function

Here is the code

```
import firebase from 'firebase'

const config = {
  apiKey: "AIzaSxxxxxxqpUeqKXI",
    authDomain: "payxxxxxa1.firebaseapp.com",
    databaseURL: "https://payxxxxxxxa1.firebaseio.com",
    projectId: "payxxxxxxja1",
    storageBucket: "payxxxxxa1.appspot.com",
    messagingSenderId: "281xxxxxxxx576"
}

firebase.initializeApp(config)

export const fire = firebase
export const ref = firebase.database().ref()
export const firebaseAuth = firebase.auth
export const messaging = firebase.messaging();
export const db = firebase.firestore();
```

Firebase version is 4.5.0

> npm list firebase > firebase@4.5.0

Am i doing wrong?

Comment: I'm seeing this issue as well, doing what you proposed did not fix the problem for me.

Comment: can you share your config code? in pastebin maybe?

Comment: https://pastebin.com/Rgs9FVrZ This is my code, cant see much wrong with it compared to your tbh...

Comment: Add `require("firebase/firestore");` on second line.

Comment: Ahh ok, thanks...! That fixed it. Could you clarify the answer i bit to reflect that you need to add it as a second line? It might just be me who didnt understand it :)

Comment: you can add it anywhere, but you must add it according to [docs](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/quickstart)

Comment: Ok, I haven't seen that. Thanks a lot for clarifying Norman

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I have resolved this issue by using `require('firebase/firestore')`

Answer (score 16):

ES6:

`import '@firebase/firestore'`

reference: https://www.npmjs.com/package/@firebase/firestore

Comment: For some reason this worked for me. I changed my imports to this 
`import firebase from '@firebase/app';`
`import '@firebase/firestore';`

Answer (score 1):

I fixed it by importing multiple libraries: firebase and firebase/firestore. That's because the firebase core library does not include the firestore library innately. So the full code to fix it is:

```
import * as firebase from 'firebase';
import 'firebase/firestore';
```

Answer (score 1):

If you're using the official firebase npm package, this is how you import it.

```
import firebase from 'firebase';
import 'firebase/firestore';
```